# How to load dynamic CSS files based on condition

Tags: php, css, dynamic

I have a index.php file which loads (require) 2 different files based on a condition.

Visiting this link will cause;

mysite.com/index.php  will load stats.php (require("stats.php");)

Visiting this link will cause;

mysite.com/index.php?auth="jgbsbsbasm" will load encry.php (`require("stats_encry.php");`)

Done with this code:

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['auth'])) require("stats.php");
else require("stats_encry.php");

?>
```

This works fine. Now my question is; I have a CSS file in the header as static;

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="cv.css">
```

What I want is now to load cv.css file for stats.php and cv1.css for stats_encry.php respectively.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your header replace

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="cv.css">
```

with

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['auth'])){ ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="cv.css">
<?php } else { ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="cv1.css">
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks but it doesn't work;

Getting a syntax error at this line ->{ <?php else { ?>}

Comment: Whoopie doo ! Works like a charm. I love stackoverflow !

Thanks a lot mate :)

Comment: you're welcome, can you accept the answer by clicking the tick on the left of the answer if this is the acceptable answer for you. cheers.

Comment: Mate can I ask you something else;

In the above code when someone goes to mysite.com/index.php?auth="jgbsbsbasm" It loads stats.php thats fine but even if i put anything in auth value it still loads the stats.php. How do i tweak this so it loads stats.php only IF the auth="jgbsbsbasm" ? I believe I have to declare this somewhere?

Comment: Try replacing the first line of the code i wrote, and your condition for requiring stats.php with : <?php if(isset($_GET['auth']) && ($_GET['auth']=="jgbsbsbasm")){ ?>

Answer (score 0):

You can use this like below syntax

```
<?php 
 if(isset($_GET['auth'])){ 
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="cv.css">';
 } else {
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="cv1.css">';
 }
 ?>
```